# List all unused domains for a Firebird database

Tags: firebird

Is there a quick way to list all Firebird domains defined for a database that are actually not used by any field ? I have a large database with many tables and many domains and it seems that a lot of them are not anymore used, so I guess it's time for a cleanup !

I think this is possible by querying the `RDB$...` system tables, but I'm unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
  f.rdb$field_name
FROM
  rdb$fields f
  LEFT JOIN rdb$relation_fields rf
    ON rf.rdb$field_source = f.rdb$field_name
WHERE
  rf.rdb$field_name IS NULL
  AND
  COALESCE(f.rdb$system_flag, 0) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks ! Could you just tell me why there is some "unnamed" domains (`RDB$5`, `RDB$9`, etc.) in the query result ? Where do they come from ? It seems they are default domain for existing tables but how can they be seen as "unused ?

Comment: Maybe these are domains for stored procedures output values.

Comment: You could add a similar join + where condition to `RDB$PROCEDURE_PARAMETERS`