# Firebird list domains and data types

Tags: firebird, ibexpert

I want to list all domains, their datatypes, and size.

## Background

I've managed to do the query, based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35434033/5372400).

The basic code takes all fields:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  rdb$fields
```

I found that I could get fields from `rdb$fields`:

1. filter fields from this request by `RDB$FIELD_NAME`
2. get field type code from `RDB$FIELD_TYPE`
3. get field length from `RDB$FIELD_LENGTH`

Reference:

https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-fields.html

---

## Question

How to combine all this to list all domains, their datatypes, and size?

I want to get only domains created by users, not automatic ones.

Comment: There is the table down the "reference" hyperlink in your question, read the comment about "RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG"

Comment: you also miss - `RDB$NULL_FLAG`, `RDB$DEFAULT_SOURCE`, `RDB$COMPUTED_SOURCE`, `RDB$FIELD_SCALE`, `RDB$SEGMENT_LENGTH`, `RDB$COLLATION_ID`, `RDB$FIELD_PRECISION`, `RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID`, `RDB$COLLATION_ID`

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
select
    t.RDB$FIELD_NAME                     Name,
    case t.RDB$FIELD_TYPE
        when 7 then 'SMALLINT'
        when 8 then 'INTEGER'
        when 10 then 'FLOAT'
        when 12 then 'DATE'
        when 13 then 'TIME'
        when 14 then 'CHAR'
        when 16 then 'BIGINT'
        when 27 then 'DOUBLE PRECISION'
        when 35 then 'TIMESTAMP'
        when 37 then 'VARCHAR'
        when 261 then 'BLOB'
    end                                  Type_Name,
    t.RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH               Chr_Length


from RDB$FIELDS t

     where coalesce( rdb$system_flag, 0) = 0 
       and not ( rdb$field_name starting with 'RDB$')
```

Also interesting, I could not find a system table with datatypes. Had to hardcode them from the [reference](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-fields.html).

Thanks for the help in comments:

## @MarkRotteveel

`RDB$TYPE` contains types, but names them differently:

> You can find all data types in the `RDB$TYPE` for RDB$FIELD_NAME =
>   'RDB$FIELD_TYPE' (although you will need to map some types as it lists
>   SMALLINT as SHORT, INTEGER as LONG, BIGINT as INT64 and VARCHAR as
>   VARYING)

Need to use field `RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH` instead of `RDB$FIELD_LENGTH`.

> Note that RDB$FIELD_LENGTH is the wrong column for char/varchar
>   columns as it is the length in bytes (which depends on the character
>   set), you need to use `RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH` for the length in
>   characters, and for numerical fields, you'll more likely need
>   RDB$FIELD_PRECISION (+ RDB$FIELD_SCALE), you are also ignoring sub
>   type information.

I needed the length of varchars only but appears RDB$FIELD_LENGTH = RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH, 1 byte = 1 char for *1 byte character set*.

> If you use a 1 byte character set [1 byte = 1 char], but for example, UTF-8 is
>   (max) 4 byte per character, so then the field_length = 4 x
>   character_length

## @Arioch

The most reliable way to get user domains:

> To an extent one may use `select * from rdb$fields where coalesce(
>   rdb$system_flag, 0) = 0 and not ( rdb$field_name starting with 'RDB$')`
>   however no one prohibits user from manually/explicitly creating column
>   named "RDB$1234567".

Comment: `but it assumes all manually created domains have one pattern` no need for it, the "manually created" - or better to day "explicitly created" domains have a special column to tell them from automatically created - `RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG` (and to a some lesser extent, because there can be pseudo-automatic manually created ones - `RDB$FIELD_NAME`)

Comment: Just like most system tables `select * from rdb$fields where coalesce( rdb$system_flag, 0) = 0`

Comment: `where coalesce( rdb$system_flag, 0) = 0` gives me all domains, including automatically created: `RDB$1, RDB$2...`. PS. I'm sorry if I confused some terms, just wanted to be clear on what I want.

Comment: You can find all data types in the `RDB$TYPE` for `RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'RDB$FIELD_TYPE'` (although you will need to map some types as it lists `SMALLINT` as `SHORT`, `INTEGER` as `LONG`, `BIGINT` as `INT64` and `VARCHAR` as `VARYING`).

Comment: In any case, the only way to separate real domains from automatically generated domains is to check by name: if they start with `RDB$` followed by a number, then it is an automatically generated domain (or someone made a very bad choice in naming conventions)

Comment: Also note that `RDB$FIELD_LENGTH` is the wrong column for char/varchar columns as it is the length in bytes (which depends on the character set), you need to use `RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH` for the length in characters, and for numerical fields, you'll more likely need `RDB$FIELD_PRECISION` (+ `RDB$FIELD_SCALE`), you are also ignoring sub type information.

Comment: indeed... To an extent one may use `select * from rdb$fields
where coalesce( rdb$system_flag, 0) = 0 and not ( rdb$field_name starting with 'RDB$')` however no one prohibits user from manually/explicitly creating column named "RDB$1234567". Maybe there is no reliable way to tell one from another, because server, plainly, does not need this distinction. You may also check if there are more than one table column using those domains, but it is not bulletproof either. I would alert Rus Manual maintainer, but I have little hope English manual would be updated

Comment: @MarkRotteveel not only for char columns but for blob columns either, I makred those columns he has to use under the question

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I needed the length of varchars only but appears `RDB$FIELD_LENGTH` = `RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH` for varchars, 1 byte = 1 char.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov That is only the case if you use a 1 byte character set, but for example UTF-8 is (max) 4 byte per character, so then the field_length = 4 x character_length.

Comment: @Arioch "however no one prohibits user from manually/explicitly creating column named "RDB$1234567""
on FB server you can't create domains starting with RDB$ and ending with a number, if the part after the $ mark can be parsed as integer that domain won't be created:
"SQL error code = -637.
Implicit domain name RDB$100000 not allowed in user created domain."

Comment: select
  case
    when trim(substring(f.rdb$field_name from 5)) similar to '[0-9]+' then 'system_created'
    else 'user_created'
  end
from
  rdb$fields f
where
  f.rdb$system_flag = 0 and
  f.rdb$field_name like ('RDB$%')

Comment: @tcxbalage just tried on FB 2.1 - indeed, if you talk about creating DOMAINS that is prohibited. However this works fine `CREATE TABLE RDB$314159215 (  RDB$271828 INTEGER)` - so basically this is an area where FB's behavior is inconsistent and using it becomes tricky, so I would better try approaches to relying on the implementation detail, if those are possible. Now, if you check my comment you replied to - I was talking about creating COLUMN not domain :-D

Comment: you are correct, i missed that column part. my bad.
i also checked on FB3.x, there is all "RDB$" prefixed domain creation is restricted.